# What is the required parameter for casting C#

Tags: c#, casting

Minimal reproducible example
Base abstract class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace YangHandlerTool
{

    public abstract class YangNode
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is here to force YangNode constructor with Name parameter.
        /// </summary>
        private YangNode() { }
        public YangNode(string name) { Name = name; }
    }
}
```

Child that adds "Type" property

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace YangHandlerTool
{
    public class Leaf : YangNode
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public Leaf(string leafname) : base(leafname){ }

    }
}
```

Other Child that adds "Type" property

```
using System;

namespace YangHandlerTool

{
    public class LeafList : YangNode
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public LeafList(string leafname) : base(leafname) { }

    }
}
```

Main

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace YangHandlerTool

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<YangNode> yangnodes = new List<YangNode>();
            yangnodes.Add(new Leaf("leafname"));
            for (int i = 0; i < yangnodes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (IsLeaf(i))
                {
                    ///I want to call SetTypeOfNode with the intention to cast to Leaf
                    SetTypeOfNode(yangnodes[i]);
                }
                if (IsLeafList(i))
                {
                    ///I want to call SetTypeOfNode with the intention to cast to LeafList
                    SetTypeOfNode(yangnodes[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void SetTypeOfNode(YangNode inputnode)
        {
            ///Desired
            //Replace GIVENANYCLASSNAME with any given classname as parameter
            //((GIVENANYCLASSNAME)inputnode).Type = "value";

              ((Leaf)inputnode).Type = "value";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// It is 100% guaranteed that the item is a Leaf.
        /// </summary>
        private static bool IsLeaf(int index)
        {
            return index == 0;
        }
        private static bool IsLeafList(int index)
        {
            return index == 1;
        }

    }
}
```

In the function "private static void SetTypeOfNode(YangNode inputnode)" I want to be able to give a Class as parameter what to cast to. In order to spare 100+ line in my actual program of casting like:

```
((Leaf)inputnode).Type = "value";
((LeafList)inputnode).Type = "value";
((AnothertypeInheritedfromYangnode)inputnode).Type = "value";
((AnothertypeInheritedfromYangnode2)inputnode).Type = "value";
```

...

How can you pass a Classname as parameter that can be given into the casting parameter?

Comment: There's a lot of relevant information we don't have at the moment. What's the compile-time type of `TracerCurrentNode`? What's the relationship between the various types involved? Is there a base class with a `Type` property that you could cast to instead? A [mcve] would be really helpful here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Added the extra info.

Comment: Is there any reason not to put `Type` in `YangNode` instead of in all the subclasses? That way you don't need to cast at all. Or perhaps have a `TypedYangNode` class that derives from `YangNode` and that both `Leaf` and `LeafList` derive from? In that case you could just cast to `TypedYangNode`. (And you *can't* have a class called `Leaf-List` or `Leaf-list`, because that's not a valid C# identifier. It really helps if you can use valid code in the question to avoid the distraction of "What's that meant to be? It doesn't make sense...")

Comment: @JonSkeet I made a reproducible example. YangNode does not have a "Type" property because not all YangNode supports it. I could make a class between Leaf and YangNode as you said with TypedYangNode but that seems a bit overkill for 1 property. And indeed I made a typo it was LeafList not Leaf-List

Comment: 1) You don't need `private YangNode() { }` as you already have that other constructor. A default ctor is not added when you provide your own. 2) Usually a ctor in an abstract class is `protected`, as it only makes sense to call it from a derived class

Comment: "I could make a class between Leaf and YangNode as you said with TypedYangNode but that seems a bit overkill for 1 property" - it's not about how many properties are involved, it's about whether it's a useful abstraction... and it sounds like it is. If `LeafList.Type` and `Leaf.Type` are conceptually equivalent, it absolutely makes sense to put that into a common base class.